How to write to worksheet during add-in unload (shutdown)
I have an Excel VSTO add-in written in vb.net. I want to write a message to the active workbook and active sheet when the user unloads the add-in. I get a COMException HRESULT: 0x800AC472 when I try to write to the worksheet.  I can read successfully from the sheet. The add-in shutdown dialogue box remains open while the code is running. There is much information on the internet about making sure Excel is available/active etc. I have tried selecting the worksheet, selecting the cell, using cells instead of range, waiting until Excel is ready and retrying with varying wait periods. All without success.
Here is latest code:
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Debug.WriteLine("addin loaded")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
        PerformExcelOperations()
    End Sub
    Private Sub PerformExcelOperations()
        Dim activeBook As Excel.Workbook = TryCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
        Dim activeSheet As Excel.Worksheet = TryCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim success As Boolean = False
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim sleep As Integer = 1000
        If activeBook IsNot Nothing Then
            Debug.WriteLine("this workbook is " & activeBook.Name)
        End If

        If activeSheet IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim sheetName As String = activeSheet.Name
            Debug.WriteLine("Active sheet name: " & sheetName)
            'While Not success
            While success = False
                Try
                    ' Write to cell A1
                    'If activeSheet.Application.Ready Then
                    If activeSheet.Application.Interactive = True Then
                        activeSheet.Select()
                        activeSheet.Cells(1, 1).value2 = "writing to cell A1"
                        Debug.WriteLine("Value written to cell A1")
                        success = True
                    Else
                        Debug.WriteLine("app Not ready")
                        counter += 1
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) ' Wait for 1 second before retrying.
                    counter += 1
                    Debug.WriteLine("counter = " & counter)

                End Try
                If counter > 10 Then
                    Debug.WriteLine("exiting sub")
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep) ' Wait for 1 second before retrying.
                sleep = sleep - 95
                'Else
                'Debug.WriteLine("No active worksheet found")
            End While
            ' Read from cell A2
            Dim mytext As String = activeSheet.Range("A2").Value2
            Debug.WriteLine("text at A2 is " & mytext)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Here is the error message from one attempt:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800AC472): Exception
from HRESULT: 0x800AC472    at
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.Select(Object Replace)    at
Claude_Activesheet_1.ThisAddIn.PerformExcelOperations() in
C:\Users\Neil
Keron\source\repos\Claude_Activesheet_1\ThisAddIn.vb:line 31

Removing line 31 activesheet.Select() simply moves the error to the activeSheet.Cells....... line.

The code works for me.

Try this for me... 1. Change If activeSheet.Application.Interactive = True Then to If activeSheet.Application.Interactive = True And activeSheet.Application.Ready Then. 2. Also remove the line activeSheet.Select() This is not needed. 3. In Try-Catch checkif If ex.HResult = &H800AC472 Then and then show Debug.WriteLine("Excel is busy."). This will also help you narrow down the cause.

You might want to check if the workbook/worksheet is still active (not nothing) during the shutdown of the addin.There might be some timing issues?
Another option might be shutting down the addin via code (so make a button in your Addin ribbon and first do the excel stuff and then close down the addin.
dim yourAddIn as Excel.AddIn = this.Application.AddIns("AddIn”)
yourAddIn.installaed=false
I will try this later this morning it is an interesting one .

Siddharth,Thanks for your comments.  When you say that 'The code works for me' are you saying that my code as posted allows a value to be written to a cell when the add-in is being unloaded?  If so, do I have a version issue here?  I am developing this in Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 10 64 bit machine with Excel 2013 64 bit.

My Excel Developer A message box before the while statement works so clearly some part of windows is ready even if excel is not.  Can I set a flag somewhere 'behind' excel and use it to initiate my desired action after the add-in unload dialogue box has closed? Thanks & regards, Neil Keron

Ok yes I understand the reason for this. Did you already try to break it down, so basically just try some basic code:
  Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
      Try

          If Me.Application IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.Application.ActiveWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
              Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(Me.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
              sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Works ok"
          Else
              MsgBox("Error during check")
          End If

      Catch ex As Exception
          MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
      End Try
  End Sub


Ike,I don't understand the difference between comments and answers.  How do i answer MyExcelDeveloper's helpful attempts to solve my problem?

MyExcelDeveloper,  Thanks for the help.  Your code gives me an HRESULT:0x800AC472 at the line "sheet.Cells(1,1).value = "Works ok".  I've included a test of sheet ISNOT nothing which also passes.  Interestingly I can read from the sheet while the dialogue box is open.
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Class ThisAddIn
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
Debug.Print("addin loaded at " & Now)
End Sub
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
Try
If Me.Application IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.Application.ActiveWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(Me.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
If sheet IsNot Nothing Then
sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Works ok"
Else
Debug.WriteLine("sheet is nothing")
End If
Else
MsgBox("Error during check")
End If
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
Debug.Print(ex.Message)
'Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
End Try
Debug.WriteLine("try block has ended")
Dim mysheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(Me.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
Dim mytext = mysheet.Cells(2, 1).value2
Debug.WriteLine("mytext is " & mytext)
End Sub
End Class


Any clues as to why I can read from the sheet but not write to it would be gratefully appreciated.
Regards
Neil Keron

I did some further testing but I think it is going to be a hard one. It’s best to avoid accessing Excel objects like ActiveWorkbook or Worksheets during the shutdown process because the Excel application might not be in a stable state.
When the user disables the addin via the developer-comm addins option, the excel dialog stays open until the dialog is shutdown. When the COM Add-ins dialog is open and the add-in is being disabled, Excel is in a limited or non-interactive state, which is probably why it fails.
I tested it using below code so “.Interactive” is ok, but “.Ready” stays false, even with waitloop and doevents.
            If Me.Application.Interactive = True Then
            isContinue = True
        Else
            MsgBox("excel is in edit mode")
            Application.Interactive = True
            If Me.Application.Interactive = True Then
                isContinue = True
            Else
                MsgBox("excel is still in edit mode")
            End If

        End If

        If isContinue = True Then
            If Me.Application.Ready = True Then
                'ok, now all should work
                isContinue = True
            Else
                MsgBox("excel is not ready")
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
                Thread.Sleep(2000)
                isContinue = Me.Application.Ready
            End If

        End If

So to be honest, It might be a difficult one to achive. Have you thought about preventing users to disable the addin eg via grouppolicies or another code which checks the registry or something like that?

MyExcelDeveloper,  Many thanks for your efforts on this one.  It looks as though I will have to rely on message boxes and some intelligence on the part of the user, rather than trying to make my add-in completely idiot proof.
